# How a make a comparison values on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When the user clicks on the button, you need to compare the values ​​in certain fields and display the values ​​according to the template.

I know this is a very stupid question, but I can't make it so that all values ​​are "true" and the function is considered executed and the button works out the correct values

I try like this

```
function serviceCheck() {
  function serviceCheck1() {
    var CasePageServiceSelector = document.getElementById('CasePageServicePact00d7746a-0675-49ac-8608-323407985e07ComboBoxEdit-el').value;
    var ServiceDocument = 'Case';
    if (CasePageServiceSelector === ServiceDocument){
       console.log('1')
    }
  }
  function serviceCheck2() {
    var CasePageServiceCategSelector = document.getElementById('CasePageServiceCategoryComboBoxEdit-el').value;
    var ServiceCateg = 'Talker';
    if (CasePageServiceCategSelector === ServiceCateg){
       console.log('2!')
    }
}
  function serviceCheck3() {
    var CasePageServiceItemSelector = document.getElementById('CasePageServiceItemComboBoxEdit-el').value;
    var ServiceItem = '4. Problem';
    if (CasePageServiceItemSelector === ServiceItem){
       console.log('3')
    }
  }
} 

function ChangeSecondTA() {
  let Theme = $('#CasePageSubjectTextEdit-el').val('template');
  let Symptoms = $('#CasePageSymptomsHtmlEdit-el').val('template2 ');
}

         
function onButtonClick(event) {
   try {
     alert(serviceCheck)
   } catch (error) {
     console.error("error: ", error);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you write the function `serviceCheck()` and you call it using: `alert(serviceCheck)`

Why do you use alert, if your function does not return anything?

Secondly, you write three functions `serviceCheck`1-3`()` however you newer call these functions.

you need write something like this:

```js
function serviceCheck() {
  let in1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  let in2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

  if (in1 == in2) {
    alert('true');
  } else {
    alert('false');
  }
}

function onButtonClick() {
  serviceCheck();
};
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <button onclick="onButtonClick()">input1 == input2 ?</button>
  <br><input id='input1' type="text" value="55">
  <input id='input2' type="text" value="55">
</body>

</html>
```